Scene where instructor talks with odd, stressed pauses and expressions to squad in military/industrial building
In the scene an instructor is instructing/briefing people (soldiers I think). The camera is facing the instructor. You can see several people facing the instructor standing side by side with their backs to the camera. The camera is elevated. The scene is rather monochromatic. Industrial or military, but indoors and not a big room. I think behind the instructor there was a wall.
The scene is funny mainly because of the weird/paranoid facial expression of the instructor, who also speaks weirdly and pauses unusually. The actor's name is not known to me, but I think I have seen his face in another movies.
In general the instructor only appears in this one scene (or maybe in another one, but without any meaning). The instructor is not a main character like in Full Metal Jacket.
I first thought the scene is from Avatar, but I can't check and I think it might not fit in the movie. Also I couldn't find the actor in the Avatar cast on IMDB.
The movie should be no more than 10 years old. Also it is playing in the present or future. Definitely rather an action movie, maybe science fiction. It's not a funny movie, but the scene was funny to me.
It was an US production, the movie was in color and not animated.
Not Hot Shots. Not Avatar. Please don't stick too much to the word "soldier". It is a unit, a squad, but pretty sure not a real world military unit. It's probably not a war movie, since I don't like war movies too much. The best hint I can give is the wide open eyes of the instructor and the strange pauses he makes. He is not loudly or angrily speaking, just weird and more or with a paranoid facial expression.
Any ideas?

Doesn't quiet match, but could he be Admiral Benson from Hot Shots!

Also, if it's really Avatar, then you're probably thinking of this character.

Feels a little generic that can fit way too many movies with a military theme, anything else that can help narrow it down more?

Not Hot Shots. Not Avatar.
Please don't stick too much to the word "soldier". It is a unit, a squad, but pretty sure not a real world military unit. It's probably not a war movie, since I don't like war movies too much. It could be a science fiction movie with some humor in it. Something like Edge of Tomorrow, Transformers or MiB. Might also be not SciFi, but just action. SciFi is just a guess.
The best hint I can give is the wide open eyes of the intructor and the strange pauses he makes. He is not loudly or angrily speaking, just weird and more or with a paranoid facial expression.

"who also speaks weirdly and pauses unusually." It's not William Shatner, is it?

Starship Troopers Welcome to the Roughnecks scene
Edit (sorry, new to posting, but will try to improve): 
In this clip from Starship Troopers linked above:

camera is facing the instructor
several people facing the instructor standing side by side
The camera is elevated at one point
The scene is rather monochromatic. Industrial or military, indoors and not a big room. 
camera perspective is elevated (@ 1:51 in the linked clip)
the instructor (actor Michael Ironside) has weird expressions. 


Welcome to Movies & TV! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here: explain why you think this movie matches the question, and provide the link for reference.

Much improved, good edit! Hopefully this answer will get a few more upvotes now
